# Derivative-free learning algorithm in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a derivative-free learning algorithm in Tensorflow. So a learning algorithm which does not use Backpropagation, as for example discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235862/is-it-possible-to-train-a-neural-network-without-backpropagation).

As far as I understand, the default Optimizers all implement backpropagation.
I could manipulate the values of the gradients as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer):

```
# Create an optimizer.
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
grads_and_vars = opt.compute_gradients(loss, <list of variables>)

# grads_and_vars is a list of tuples (gradient, variable).  Do whatever you
# need to the 'gradient' part, for example cap them, etc.
capped_grads_and_vars = [(MyCapper(gv[0]), gv[1]) for gv in grads_and_vars]

# Ask the optimizer to apply the capped gradients.
opt.apply_gradients(capped_grads_and_vars)
```

But I don't see a way to implement a learning algorithm which does not rely on backproapgation. Additionally, the forumla I want to use does not need the derivatives, so I think it's unnecessary to calculate the gradients at all?

Is there any way to modify/ create an Optimizer to use another way than backpropagation to adjust the weights?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't implemented my own optimizer so far, I examined the TensorFlow Architecture closely because I am currently writing a Wrapper for it.

As far as I understand, you can implment your own optimizer by extending the [tf.train.Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer) Class (just like all other optimizers that are currently implemented in TensorFlow).

Casually speaking, an optimizer in TensorFlow consist of a Python (or any other Client Language) and a C++ Part. The latter implements the core functionality, i.e. the Ops in the TensorFlow Graph like the training Ops defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc).

The Python part of an optimizer adds the Ops to the graph definition. It supplies the parameters that get passed to the Ops and does some of the high-level management of the optimizer.

So here is what I suggest you could try:

1. Write your own implementation of the base optimizer class.
2. To implement your formula, you have to define an Op, as it is explained in the [Adding an Op Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op).